# Running Nutch crawls on EMR (newbie)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nutch, emr

I'm a first time EMR/Hadoop user and first time Apache Nutch user.  I'm trying to use Apache Nutch 2.1 to do some screen scraping.  I'd like to run it on hadoop, but don't want to setup my own cluster (one learning curve at a time).  So I'm using EMR.  And I'd like S3 to be used for output (and whatever input I need).

I've been reading the setup wikis for Nutch:

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial

And they've been very helpful in getting me up to speed on the very basics of nutch.  I realize I can build nutch from source, preconfigure some regexes, then be left with a hadoop friendly jar:

```
$NUTCH_HOME/runtime/deploy/apache-nutch-2.1.job
```

Most of the tutorials culminate in a crawl command being run.  In the Hadoop examples, it's:

```
hadoop jar nutch-${version}.jar org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

And in the local deployment example it's something like:

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

My question is as follows.  What do I have to do to get my apache-nutch-2.1.job to run on EMR?  What arguments to I pass it?  For the hadoop crawl example above, the "urls" file is already on hdfs with seed URLs.  How do I do this on EMR?  Also, what do I specify on the command line to have my final output to go S3 instead of HDFS?

Comment: any news on this question?

Answer (score 0):

So to start off, this can not really to be done using the GUI. Instead I got nutch working using the AWS Java API.

I have my seed files located in s3, and I transfer my output back to s3.

I use the dsdistcp jar to copy the data from s3 to hdfs.

Here is my basic step config. MAINCLASS is going to be the package details of your nutch crawl. Something like org.apach.nutch.mainclass.

```
    String HDFSDIR = "/user/hadoop/data/";

    stepconfigs.add(new StepConfig()
            .withName("Add Data")
            .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW)
            .withHadoopJarStep(new HadoopJarStepConfig(prop.getProperty("S3DISTCP"))
            .withArgs("--src", prop.getProperty("DATAFOLDER"), "--dest", HDFSDIR)));

    stepconfigs.add(new StepConfig()
            .withName("Run Main Job")
            .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CONTINUE)
            .withHadoopJarStep(new HadoopJarStepConfig(nutch-1.7.jar)
            .withArgs("org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl", prop.getProperty("CONF"), prop.getProperty("STEPS"), "-id=" + jobId)));


    stepconfigs.add(new StepConfig()
            .withName("Pull Output")
            .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW)
            .withHadoopJarStep(new HadoopJarStepConfig(prop.getProperty("S3DISTCP"))
            .withArgs("--src", HDFSDIR, "--dest", prop.getProperty("DATAFOLDER"))));

    new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(new PropertiesCredentials(new File("AwsCredentials.properties")), proxy ? new ClientConfiguration().withProxyHost("dawebproxy00.americas.nokia.com").withProxyPort(8080) : null)
                .runJobFlow(new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withName("Job: " + jobId)
                .withLogUri(prop.getProperty("LOGDIR"))
                .withAmiVersion(prop.getProperty("AMIVERSION"))
                .withSteps(getStepConfig(prop, jobId))
                .withBootstrapActions(getBootStrap(prop))
                .withInstances(getJobFlowInstancesConfig(prop)));
```

Comment: Please ask specific questions and I will try and help out more. Use the above as a starting point